# install lxml package. I am using python 2.7.5 in windows 7

Tags: python, lxml

i want to install lxml package. I am using python 2.7.5 in windows 7. I am using mingw compiler. After searching through the answers in stackoverflow and other sites, I removed the problem of "unable to find vcvarsall.bat". But now the problem which is coming is it is showing a fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory. And then it is showing an error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to download it form [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), website. It provides some unofficial binaries. Chose the right python version and install.

Comment: actually my main aim is to install turbogear as a full stack. But since it requires C compiler (and lxml also has the same reqwuirement),  I decided to first "pip install lxml" to use python-docx and assured myself that any python module can be install which requires C dependencies. Here my query is: Is this problem always going to occur when "pip install vy" which needs C dependencies

Comment: Yes, it most certainly is. This is why its better to develop on Linux or Unix when it comes to Python that has C extensions or dependencies, building C can be often difficult.

Comment: what is your opinion about using cygwin.

Comment: @user2963441 Problematic at best. There _is_ a way to compile C on windows, but its not easy, and I think its better that you ask another question instead of adding to the comments.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac you should actually write out the link/URL address... since they often break.  This way someone could find it in the future if it does by googling for it and hopefully finding a mirror